# UniSwap v2 Subgraph return 0 for Volume in USD and ETH

Tags: solidity, uniswap, amm, subgraph

I've forked Uniswap v2 contracts including WETH, and Deployed on Rinkeby. the functionality of Creating Pools, adding and removing liquidity works fine.

Now to get the stats like TVL, Volume, 24hr volume, 7-day volume, etc I 'v forked the subgraph code of this repo https://github.com/ArchTaqi/uniswap-v2-subgraph/tree/rinkeby and deployed it for rinkbey with added my factory contract and WETH address (that was passed to Router address of uniswap),

Afterward, I created a couple of Pairs of ERC-20 tokens, adding Liq. Now when I get stats from Subgraph it returns the token data but Zero in VolumeUSD, VolumeETH, and ReserveETH.

```
{
  "data": {
    "uniswapFactories": [
      {
        "id": "0xe7f16Be722602d5d12d3a1f5cFd91D34d8bbC0AC",
        "pairCount": 7,
        "totalVolumeUSD": "0",
        "totalVolumeETH": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
}

and 

    {
  "data": {
    "pair": {
      "token0": {
        "id": "0x061d0c9f280781da4d550539bf43339a05be3e59",
        "symbol": "OTG",
        "name": "Octagon",
        "derivedETH": "0"
      },
      "token1": {
        "id": "0x33d499d24c5b0dba57860ec56dd3a79161073184",
        "symbol": "WETH",
        "name": "Wrapped Ether",
        "derivedETH": "0"
      },
      "reserve0": "1000",
      "reserve1": "1",
      "reserveUSD": "0",
      "trackedReserveETH": "0",
      "token0Price": "1000",
      "token1Price": "0.001",
      "volumeUSD": "0",
      "txCount": "1",
      "totalSupply": "31.622776601683792319",
      "reserveETH": "0"
    }
  }
}
```

See in above response `totalVolumeUSD`, `totalVolumeETH`, `derivedETH`, `reserveETH`, `volumeUSD`, `reserveUSD` is all zero.

I've also Created ETH, DAI pair added ETH, DAI and ETH/DAI addresses in the code. https://github.com/zsulocal/uniswap-v2-subgraph/compare/master...ArchTaqi:uniswap-v2-subgraph:rinkeby

But still getting Zero values, What's wrong here?

Comment: Where is your sufgraph deployed to? Is it synchronised?

Comment: On Graph hosted service at this link https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/atlas-dex/atlassubgraph, yes it's synced.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully it will help someone who is looking for the answear.

I've been facing the same issue and spent a couple of days figuring out the reason.

So the issue is the addresses you provide all over the place to the graph, like `WETH_ADDRESS` and `USDC_WETH_PAIR`. You should provide them in `lower case` to make sure IDs in the graph are equal to the addresses provided, e.g.:

The address `0xa510358AA96eB9D09b84a8D9037EF51F010DA086` should become '0xa510358aa96eb9d09b84a8d9037ef51f010da086' and so on.